# ggplot2: How do you select a subset of factor levels to be grouped into a single facet

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to compare one level of a variable against the combined influence of all other variables. I would like to do this with a facet plot.

For instance:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(price, colour = cut)) + geom_density() + facet_grid(~clarity)
```

This provides a faceted plot of all the factor levels in clarity. However, what I would like to have is a density plot of I1 in the first facet and a density plot of ~(I1) in the second facet.

So I would like to produce a comparison of the following using the facet feature of ggplot2:

```
ggplot(subset(diamonds, (clarity == "I1")) , aes(price, colour = cut)) + geom_density()

ggplot(subset(diamonds, !(clarity == "I1")) , aes(price, colour = cut)) + geom_density()
```

I can see how I could define a new column in the dataframe and use that as the factor in facet_grid, but I suspect there are much better ways to do this.

Comment: I think that it will be easier to make new column to use in facet_grid()

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new column(better solution) or use `gridExtra` package:

```
library(gridExtra)
p1 <- ggplot(subset(diamonds, (clarity == "I1")) , aes(price, colour = cut)) + geom_density()
p2 <- ggplot(subset(diamonds, !(clarity == "I1")) , aes(price, colour = cut)) + geom_density()
grid.arrange(p1,p2)
```